# I'm unable to install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, 16.04

I'm new user to Ubuntu.I want to install Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm unable to do that because my screen freezes at Ubuntu logo.

[image: Here is my Image]

Comment: Press Tab or Esc on this screen and see what it shows

Answer (score 2):

[Try to set nomodeset](https://superuser.com/questions/611980/edit-boot-menu-when-booting-from-a-live-cd), I had the same problem with 14.04 on an older laptop. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

check out the installation guide for your platform: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/

this also includes a section "Troubleshooting the Installation Process": e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch05s04.html

Answer (score 0):

Please post the output while your system shows you the splash screen. Simply, press `ESC` when it shows you the splash screen and post your findings. Otherwise, it is not possible for us to help you out without knowing what is causing the problem.